# Does "what a good days I had" is correct?

Tags: grammar

Does phrase "what a good days I had" is correct? or I should say "What good days I had"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "what" to begin an exclamation is common in English, usually "what + noun" (e.g. "What a good day!"), or "what + noun + verb" (e.g. "what a good day this is!" or "what good days these are!"). I suspect you're confused about how to construct a "what" explanation.

You use "what..." not "what a..." with a plural noun. [Multimedia English](https://multimedia-english.com/grammar/exclamations-with-how-what-12) discusses this and says explicitly "the article 'a' is only used with countable singular nouns", so this is evidently a common misunderstanding.

To use this construction correctly you need to have a noun or valid noun phrase for the first component after "what", which would mean "what good days", not "a good days" (ugh). Then add the verb to give "**What good days I had!"**

Note that if you're learning English you should ask on English Language Learners Stack Exchange at https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Source: Cambridge dictionaries: *English Grammar Today*: Grammar > Words, sentences and clauses > Clauses and sentences > Exclamations
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/exclamations

Comment: 'Note that if you're learning English you should ask on English Language Learners Stack Exchange'  really indicates the demand for a close-vote rather than an 'answer'.